# Sklearn: Cross validation for grouped data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to implement a cross validation scheme on grouped data. I was hoping to use the GroupKFold method, but I keep getting an error. what am I doing wrong?
The code (slightly different from the one I used--I had different data so I had a larger n_splits, but everythign else is the same)

```
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
#generate data
x=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
y= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
group=np.array([1,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,0,0,2)]
#grid search
gkf = GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x,y,group)
subsample = np.arange(0.3,0.5,0.1)
param_grid = dict( subsample=subsample)
rgr_xgb = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=50)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(rgr_xgb, param_grid, cv=gkf, n_jobs=-1)
result = grid_search.fit(x, y)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-143-11d785056a08>", line 8, in <module>
result = grid_search.fit(x, y)

File "/home/student/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 813, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

 File "/home/student/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 566, in _fit
n_folds = len(cv)

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

changing the line

```
gkf = GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x,y,group)
```

to

```
gkf = GroupKFold( n_splits=3)
```

does not work either. The error message is then:

```
'GroupKFold' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What version of `sklearn` do you have? `GridSearchCV`'s `cv` parameter should normally take a generator.

Answer (score 29):

The [`split`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L322) function of `GroupKFold` *yields* the training and test indices pair one at a time.  You should call `list` on the split value to get them all in a list so the length can be computed:

```
gkf = list(GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x,y,group))
```

Comment: It seems to work. However, I tried `gkf = list(GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x,y,group))` and `gkf = list(GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x[:-100],y[:-100],group[:-100))` and for both cases, trained it with `grid_search.fit(x, y)`. Both of them run smoothly with almost the same results, while I expected the second to fail (since it has less elements on gkf than on fit). How can I check its behavior?

Comment: Also tried `gkf = list(GroupKFold( n_splits=3).split(x,y,group))` with `grid_search.fit(x[:100], y[:100])` and it does raises an strange error `IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for size 100`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an optimization of Moses's answer. It may be memory-limiting to store all splits simultaneously, so we could just wrap around the original yield mechanism to return only one train/test split at a time

```
class KFoldHelper:
    def __init__(self, kfold: sklearn.model_selection._split._BaseKFold, x: np.ndarray,
                 classes: np.ndarray = None, groups: np.ndarray = None):
        self.iter = kfold.split(x, y = classes, groups=groups)

    def __iter__(self):
        for idxsTrain, idxsTest in self.iter:
            yield idxsTrain, idxsTest
```

Now we can call

```
kfold = KFoldHelper(GroupKFold(n_splits=3), x, classes=y, groups=group)
```

and

```
GridSearchCV(rgr_xgb, param_grid, cv=kfold, n_jobs=-1)
```